# Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address [...]

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to follow up some tutorial I bought, by doing the Security in Symfony2, but I get this error.

app/config/security.yml

```
firewalls:
    # ...
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    # ...
```

/src/SF2/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
UserBundle:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/user.yml"
    prefix: /
```

/src/SF2/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/user.yml

```
user_login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: "UserBundle:Login:login" }

user_login_check:
    path:     /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: "UserBundle:Login:loginCheck" }
```

Above are my routes and security configuration. Now, the form I want to display.

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title 'Login' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        {% if error %}
            <div>
                {{ error.message }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="{{ login_check }}" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control"/>

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control"/>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The `loginAction` from `loginController` is the same provided in Symfony's official website, and the `loginCheckAction` is empty. I'm following a tutorial's instructions, but I made a little bit different about the routes. He used annotations, but I want to use YML files because I find it more organized.

The error happens when I try to access `/login`. If I remove the security configurations and `{{ login_check }}` from the from, everything works.

What could I be missing?

Comment: What is the variable `login_check`? Should be `action="{{ path('user_login_check') }}"` or `action="/login_check"`.

Comment: Good, it solved half of the problem. By putting this way it showed the form from view without saying `login_check` does not exist. What's up with the `user_` before it?

Comment: It's the name of you route!

Comment: The tutorial I am following is from 2012. It is no surprise there are some differences. Back to the main problem, if I comment or erase the configuration in `firewalls`, the login form is shown perfectly. I still have to understand what happened.

Comment: Follow this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: I've got the solution. I had to put `anonymous: ~` in `secured_area`. Thank you @malcolm for showing me up the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution. I had to put `anonymous: ~` in `secured_area`. Thank you @malcolm for showing me up the official documentation.